# Jump instruction can be performed in two clock cycles instead of three clock cycles in multi-cycle datapath

Tags: cpu-architecture

In multi-cycle datapath, the first and second cycle is similar for all types of instructions.

The first cycle is Instruction fetch and the second cycle is instruction decode and register fetch.

Jump is performed in three clock cycles. two clock cycles are those I mentioned above. and the third one is left shift 26 LSB of instruction so that we have 28 bit and then add 4 MSB bits of PC to it so we get a 32-bit address and we set it to the pc.

but we can do the third cycle of jump in the second clock cycle, so that jump instruction can be finished in two clock cycles.

Comment: Definitely, this can be done. In the standard RISC pipeline, this is generally done in the ID stage to reduce branch penalty to 1 cycle. The architectural modifications are to move the adder that is used to add the immediate to PC in the second phase and insert a small comparator whose output is connected to PC control at the outputs of register file.

Comment: It must be some reason if there is no reason why should they worsen their performance? what is the reason behind this? (consider that the architecture is not pipeline and is multicycle in mips)

Comment: Multicycle MIPS never existed. It is just a (very good) didactic tool. The only drawback to transfer branch in the ID stage is that you have, once registers have been read, to go through a comparator and the PC multiplexer and it may increase the critical path and slow down clock.  But there is no theoretical reason against that. And in practise the critical path generally includes the memory and is not in the ID stage.